# How to compare same table between Hive, Teradata

Tags: python, hive, comparison, teradata, vertica

We have a situation where we copy same tables to Hive , Teradata and vertica .

We have to test and confirm whether the tables were copied exactly between all.

As of now we use python to download the tables to csv and compare them, but due to sizes of the tables we are finding difficulties in this approach.

```
with open('hive.csv', 'r') as t1, open('teradat.csv', 'r') as t2:
    hivedata = t1.readlines()
    teradata = t2.readlines()

with open('differences.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    for line in teradata:
        if line not in hivedata:
            outFile.write(line)
```

Can someone suggest best way to compare the tables between any two at a given time.

I can use python, spark / pyspark to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

To compare, you must invariably bring the two tables' data into the same location.

Your Python approach brings all of the data out of both databases to a third location, which is the slowest possible approach.

The *best* would be to get the agreement of all people involved to calculate a numeric hash value that, in all of Hive, Teradata and Vertica, would return the exact same integer with the exact same table row data. Summing all hash values on each table on each platform, and getting the same result everywhere should sufficiently show the data is the same. Someone could argue, however, that you could run into hash collisions, and therefore this is not absolutely accurate (even if the hash collision risk is very, very low).

If you absolutely *have* to compare the actual table data - bring only one table's data across to another database. In Vertica (probably the best shot, as it can be pretty impressive in performance with this type of operation), `CREATE TABLE cmp_<table_name> LIKE <table_name>;`, then find the fastest way for you to transfer the data from the other database into Vertica. And export to CSV in a single thread is often not the fastest. Consider several parallel jobs, each treating their subset of the table's data. And consider programs that to that in parallel, reading into memory and using that memory to populate an INSERT with parameter markers, in very big arrays. Finally, `SELECT * FROM <table_name> EXCEPT SELECT * FROM cmp_<table_name>;` . That query should return an empty row set.

Good luck -